# Dockerizing spring boot application with oracle database

Tags: oracle, maven, spring-boot, java-8

How to dockerize spring boot application + oracle database?

I want to create a docker file for spring boot application. for this I am using Dockerfile, Docker-compose.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is pretty generic, but as main guidelines i would say
you should create two images, one for the oracle db, and another for spring. 
Later you can include these two in your compose file.

For building an oracle image you can have a look here:
[Oracle Database on Docker](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/README.md)

and for building a docker image with spring:
 [Spring Boot Docker](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker)

Comment: I have created docker image for spring boot application, but when we integrate oracle data base we need to add dependency to pom.xml and ojdbc.jar in class path. I stuck at this point

Comment: You can add an ojdbc driver dependency from here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc7/12.1.0.2

Comment: If we want to work with oracle database we need to add dependency in pom.xml and specify jar to class-path also. because oracle not allow to add dependency directly